# How do I prevent Nose from running and reporting duplicate tests?

Tags: python, django, nose

I'm using [django-nose](http://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose#readme) to test our Django projects. It is common to split large test suites inside an application in Django like this:

```
myapp/
  __init__.py
  models.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_views.py
    test_models.py
  views.py
```

`tests/__init__.py` would look like this:

```
from test_views import *
from test_models import *
```

Since Django will look for tests in `myapp.tests`, everything works as expected. Nose on the other hand will find the tests in `tests_*.py` **and** import them again in `__init__.py`. This results in the total number of tests reported being double what they should be.

Any ways around this problem (other than never using sub-modules) that will correctly report the tests with both django-nose and the default Django test runner?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ways around this problem (other
>   than never using sub-modules)

Don't include the lines

```
from test_views import *
from test_models import *
```

in `tests/__init__.py`.  What are those lines accomplishing?

Comment: "Django will look for tests in `myapp.tests`"

Comment: Really?  If you omit, the tests run 0 times, and if you include, the tests run 2 times?  That is bizarre behavior.

I use standard nose (as opposed to django-nose), so perhaps my expectations are wrong.  However, my understanding is that the purpose of nose is to automatically find tests, thus avoiding extraneous code (e.g., unnecessary imports).

Comment: If you want to use either Django test discovery or nose test discovery, this will be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the import conditionally.

The following does the trick, assuming you are setting `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'`:

```
from django.conf import settings
if 'nose' not in getattr(settings, 'TEST_RUNNER', ''):
    # Support Django test discovery
    from .test_views import *
    from .test_models import *
```

In this way, you will be able to support both the normal Django test discovery and nose test discovery without duplicating tests for the latter, or losing them for the former.